# Can the bound text be read in a TextFieldStyle?

Tags: swiftui

I'm creating a custom `TextFieldStyle` that behaves differently whether the bound text is empty or not. This is what I have:

```
struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.myColor1)
            .background(Color.myColor2)
            .font(.custom(!???.isEmpty ? .myBold1 : .myOther2,...))
    }
}
```

In the `font` modifier, how can I read the bound text to determine different styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the text in as a parameter:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("default text", text: $text)
            .textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle(text: text))
    }
}

struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    var text : String
    
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(text.isEmpty ? Color.red : Color.blue)
            .font(text.isEmpty ? .system(size: 12, weight: .bold, design: .default) :
                    .system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .default))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great if you are only applying the .textFieldStyle modifier to the TextField itself, but it doesn't work if you want to apply .textFieldStyle to a parent view so that all TextField children get the specified style. Is there any way around this to check if the field is empty from inside MyTextFieldStyle?

Comment: Yes -- that is happening already in my answer. See anywhere it says `text.isEmpty`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Is it possible to not have to pass the text value into MyTextFieldStyle? Each value will be different if used on a group of TextFields. It would require that I use the .textFieldStyle modifier on every TextField. I could not make this style default for an entire section of my app.

I'd like to get the value from inside MyTextFieldStyle even if I have to use introspection.

Comment: Sounds like you should start a new question with the relevant code included.

Comment: Thanks, asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471891/can-the-textfield-value-be-used-in-textfieldstyle).