# Can the TextField value be used in TextFieldStyle?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to get the `TextField` value in `TextFieldStyle` without having to pass in the text value into the custom `TextFieldStyle` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498160/can-the-bound-text-be-read-in-a-textfieldstyle)? I'd like to be able to apply this style to a parent view so that all child `TextField`s use the custom `TextFieldStyle`. For example...

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text1 = ""
    @State var text2 = ""
    @State var text3 = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Text field 1", text: $text1)
            TextField("Text field 2", text: $text2)
            TextField("Text field 3", text: $text3)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle())

    }
}

struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {    
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding()
            .background(text.isEmpty ? Color.red : Color.blue) // `text` is not available, how can I get it?
    }
}
```

If I had to pass in the `TextField`'s value into `MyTextFieldStyle`, this would not be possible and I would need to use `.textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle(text: text))` after every `TextField`. This is not ideal as in my use case there will be many text fields used at varying levels in my view hierarchy.

I am okay with using introspection/combine if that is what is necessary.

Comment: How about making your own `TextField` instead?

Comment: I am trying to use styles instead of creating custom views where possible. This has worked for all other things I can style (ButtonStyle, ToggleStyle, etc). I am trying to be consistent and make things easier by using built-in SwiftUI views for future contributors of our project.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend writing your own text field that wraps a `TextField`.

```
struct MyTextField: View {
    let label: LocalizedStringKey
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(label, text: $text)
            .padding()
            .background(text.isEmpty ? .red : .blue)
    }
}
```

If you want to create a custom `myTextFieldStyle` modifier to apply custom styles to `MyTextField`s, you can also do that. Now you can pass a `text: String` through your own style's `Configuration`. See jrturton's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77190340/5133585) to my question for how to do this.

Here is an example implementation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text1 = ""
    @State var text2 = ""
    @State var text3 = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyTextField(label: "Text field 1", text: $text1)
            MyTextField(label: "Text field 2", text: $text2)
            MyTextField(label: "Text field 3", text: $text3)
        }
        .myTextFieldStyle(RedWhenEmptyStyle())
    }
}

struct MyTextField: View {
    let label: LocalizedStringKey
    @Binding var text: String
    // pass the specific style implementations to the environment...
    @Environment(\.myTextFieldStyle) var style
    var body: some View {
        AnyView(
            style.makeBody(
                configuration: MyTextFieldConfiguration(
                    text: text,
                    textField: AnyView(TextField(label, text: $text))
                )
            )
        )
    }
}

struct MyTextFieldConfiguration {
    let text: String
    let textField: AnyView
}

protocol MyTextFieldStyle {
    associatedtype Body: View
    // now in the implementation you can use configuration.text to get the text!
    func makeBody(configuration: MyTextFieldConfiguration) -> Body
}

struct DefaultMyTextFieldStyle: MyTextFieldStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: MyTextFieldConfiguration) -> some View {
        configuration.textField
    }
}

struct RedWhenEmptyStyle: MyTextFieldStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: MyTextFieldConfiguration) -> some View {
        configuration.textField
            .background(configuration.text.isEmpty ? .red : .blue)
    }
}

struct MyTextFieldStyleKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: any MyTextFieldStyle = DefaultMyTextFieldStyle()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var myTextFieldStyle: any MyTextFieldStyle {
        get { self[MyTextFieldStyleKey.self] }
        set { self[MyTextFieldStyleKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension View {
    func myTextFieldStyle(_ style: some MyTextFieldStyle) -> some View {
        environment(\.myTextFieldStyle, style)
    }
}
```

---

Note that you are not supposed to create your own `TextFieldStyle`s. Its requirement, `_body`, starts with an underscore. This means it is not a stable API yet.

If you *really* want to do introspection, this works (for iOS 17.0 at least). You basically get the `_text` property of the text field as a `Binding<String>` and read from it.

```
struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: configuration)
        let text = mirror.children.first { $0.label == "_text" }?.value as! Binding<String>
        configuration
            .padding()
            .background(text.wrappedValue.isEmpty ? Color.red : Color.blue)
    }
}
```

This will probably break in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be an acceptable approach using pointers. It might be more performant than using Mirror as well.

```swift
struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        let textBinding: Binding<String> = withUnsafePointer(to: configuration) { pointer in
            pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: Binding<String>.self, capacity: 1) { pointer in
                pointer.pointee
            }
        }
        configuration
            .padding()
            .background(textBinding.wrappedValue.isEmpty ? Color.red : Color.blue)
    }
}
```